# Need a subgroup of a group $G$ which is maximal in $G$ but not normal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I've just read that any maximal subgroup of $p-group$,$P$ is normal in $P$.Now,I need to know that is there any subgroup of a $G$ which is maximal in $G$ but not normal in $G$?

Comment: Do you mean "Is there a group $G$ which has a subgroup $H$ such that $H$ is maximal in $G$ but not normal in $G$"? Using the word "arbitrary" makes your question look like "Is it true that for every group $G$, there is a subgroup $H$ which is maximal but not normal?" (which, as you've stated, is false: let $G$ be any $p$-group).

Comment: There are non-cyclic simple groups like $A_5$.  Those have no non-trivial normal subgroups.  But of course they have non-trivial subgroups.

Comment: @PatrickStevens:Thanks.I did'nt know this.

Answer (score 2):

For  example,

$$\left\{\,(1),\,(12)\,\right\}\;\;\;\text{is maximal and non-normal in}\;\;\;S_3$$

Comment: :Since $(132)(12)(132)^{-1}=(13)  $ $\notin $ {$(1),(12)$}.So it is not normal in $S_3$.But,how can we show that {$(1),(12)$} is maximal in $S_3$?

Comment: @AashiqRaza If there were a subgroup $H$ between $S_3$ and the example in the answer (denote it by $G$), then $|H|$ would divide $|S_3|=6$ and be divisible by $|G|=2$. So we have $|H|$ is either $2$ or $6$, which correspond to $H=G$ and $H=S_3$, respectively.                                                 Note that the similar proof shows that $S_{p-1}$ is non-normal but maximal in $S_p$ for all prime $p$.

Comment: @heptagon: i got.Thanks!! for the generalization.